# Location of contour lines

Tags: python, matplotlib

Below is my code and plot:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline

delta = 0.00025
A=0
x = np.arange(0, 0.10, delta)
y = np.arange(0, 0.1, delta)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = A*(X**2+Y**2)+2*X*Y

manual_locations = [(0.1,0.1), (0.2,0.2), (0.3,0.3), 
                    (0.015, 0.015), (0.00255, 0.0025), (0.00005,0.00005)]
line_widths = (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)

plt.figure()
CS = plt.contour(X, Y, Z, 6,                        # add 6 contour lines
                 linewidths=line_widths,            # line widths
                 colors = line_colours)             # line colours

plt.clabel(CS, inline=1,                            # add labels
          fontsize=10,                             # label font size 
          manual=manual_locations)                 # label locations
plt.title('Indifference Map')        # title

plt.show()
```

[image]

It seems my manual_locations does nothing, python picks equally spaced contour lines automatically. While I want to investigate more details around 0. How can I see more curves/contour lines converging to (0,0)?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to explore parts of your data in more details is with `levels`.  This sets what Z-values to examine, and in your question you phrase this as an (x,y) location to inspect, but it's a bit backwards from how `contour` works to specify the location points directly.

You could also do inspect the (0,0) region by changing the boundaries of the plot appropriately.

Below, I use log values for `levels`, but linear values work equally well, are far more common, and are easier to interpret.  The log values just easily emphasis the part of the plot you're most interested in.

[image]

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
#%matplotlib inline

delta = 0.00025
A=0
x = np.arange(0, 0.10, delta)
y = np.arange(0, 0.1, delta)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = A*(X**2+Y**2)+2*X*Y

manual_locations = [(0.1,0.1), (0.2,0.2), (0.3,0.3), 
                    (0.015, 0.015), (0.00255, 0.0025), (0.00005,0.00005)]
line_widths = (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)

plt.figure()
CS = plt.contour(X, Y, Z, 6,                        # add 6 contour lines
                 linewidths=line_widths, 
                 #levels=np.linspace(0, .003, 20))   
                 levels=np.logspace(-5, -2, 20))

plt.clabel(CS, inline=1,                            # add labels
          fontsize=10,
          fmt="%.5f")
plt.title('Indifference Map')        # title

plt.show()
```

If you really need the contour at a specific location, you could put the (x,y) values for that location into your equation to calculate the z-value at that location, and then use this value as one of the values in the `levels` argument.